# Superlatives - "in all" vs. "of all"

Tags: superlative-degree

Example sentence: "He ran the fastest (of all) the anchors." - my coworker (an ESL teacher) wants to know specifically why we can't say "He ran the fastest (in all) the anchors".  I feel like it may just be the set usage for superlatives but I was hoping to give a little more information and not just "that's just how it is".

Is that just how it is?

Comment: What do you mean by *anchors*? For example, this makes sense: *He ran the fastest in all the anchor legs of the races that day.* In that sentence, an *anchor* isn't a person but a specific event that he could have taken part in.

Comment: Tom ran the fastest of all the *starters*. Dick ran the fastest of all the *anchors*. Harry *kicked it in* like no one else on the track. With Fast Eddie reliable as ever on the second leg, Tom, Dick and Harry made the podium that day.

Comment: "He ran the fastest of all the anchors" is correct, but you could also say "He was the fastest in the anchors group".